# Unable to get the logic behind macro and operators precedence

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The output of the  following code is 8  24  32. I understand the logic behind 8 and 24 but 32 seems very strange to me. Can somebody explain why it prints 32?

```
#define cube(x) x*x*x
void main()
{
    printf("%d ",cube(2));
    printf("%d ",16+cube(2));
    printf("%d ",16/cube(2));
}
```

Comment: wats so strange? learn about operators associativity.

Comment: Read about: Why macros are evil and their side effects.

Comment: See? you learned three things. (1) Operator precedence really *does* mean something, (2) **Always** surround macro arguments AND the final expressions with parens `#define cube(x)  ((x)*(x)*(x))`, and (3) **Don't** use macros =P

Comment: `void main()` is wrong for two reasons: 1. main returns `int`. 2. Unlike in C++, in C empty parentheses are **not equivalent to void** (but mean in K&R oldstyle a fixed but unspecified number of args).

Comment: @Jens, your last point is incomplete. `()` in a function *definition* means that the function doesn't receive an argument. This isn't a function prototype but still valid C.

Comment: how about `CUBE(i++)`? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The last `printf` gets translated to :

```
printf("%d ",16/2 * 2 * 2);
```

And that is why all macros should have surrounding parentheses:

```
#define cube(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))
```

Or just use functions and trust the compiler to inline them. Functions are almost always better.

Answer (score 3):

Macro is just a compile-time substitution of text<sup>1</sup>. So the C preprocessor will change this line:

```
 printf("%d ",16/cube(2));
```

to this line:

```
printf("%d ", 16/2*2*2);
```

**After** this text substitution is done, the compiler examines the expression. This results in the following evaluation:

```
// 16/2 is evaluated first because '/' has the same precedence as '*',
// so the tie is broken by left-to-ride order:
printf("%d ", 8*2*2);

// Then each of the '*' operators is evaluated in turn:
printf("%d ", 16*2);
printf("%d ", 32);
```

It is generally recommended to prevent operator precedence from altering how expressions in macros are interpreted by using parentheses around each use of a macro parameter and around the entire macro definition:

```
#define cube(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))
```

Note that if cube were not a macro but a function, the result would be different, because the function is fully compiled **before** an argument is passed to it:

```
int cube (int x)
{
   return x*x*x;
}
…
printf("%d ",16/cube(2)); // Prints 2.
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup>Actually, the text is parsed into preprocessor tokens and there are some other syntactic things that may occur. In large part, macro substitution is text substitution, but there can be some complications.

Comment: "_The rules of operators precedence state that division operator is evaluated before multiplication_"? Are you talking about associativity?

Comment: it'sthe same. Often precedence and associativity are synonimous: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: Yes, but someone could think that division is always evaluated before multiplication because of a greater precedence, while it's not true as you know. But maybe it's just my bad English. :)

Comment: I up-voted this because it is currently the only answer that states that macro expansion is a compile-time substitution. The others just describe results or solutions without explaining this simple fact. However, the language could be clarified. I am going to make some edits, perhaps of increasing boldness. Feel free to revert them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're under gcc compile with -E to see preprocessors output

```
gcc -E demo.c > out.c
```

This can help you next time

Comment: or  invoking directly cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Because cube is a macro,

```
16/cube(2)
```

evaluates via the preprocessor to

```
16/2*2*2
```

which comes to 32.

If you need a macro (as opposed to a function), wrap the input and output in brackets. e.g.

```
#define cube(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))
```

but I'd really use a function here.

Comment: Wrap the arguments as well `#define cube(x) ((x) * (x) * (x))`

Answer (score 0):

in the case of using macros we should be very careful. it just look like a function ,but really it is not a function. during the compile time preprocessor just expands the macro wherever it finds hence in the first use of macro

```
printf("%d ",cube(2)); expands into printf("%d",x*x*x); then it prints 8
printf("%d ",16+cube(2)); expands into  printf("%d",16+x*x*x); then it prints 24
printf("%d ",16/cube(2)); expands into printf("%d",16/x*x*x); but prints 32
```